# How to print the List view in Wordpress for custom data

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering if there is any method that can be used to display the custom data in Wordpress like list format.

See example in this image: i.stack.imgur.com/oiVdR.png

When we hover on the particular post, we see options like Edit etc. and when mouse goes-off, then these options disappear from there.

Comment: Look . http://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [WP_List_Table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table) class for that. See also a [guide](http://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/), mentioned by @Noman in comment.